# After YouTube video play app doesn't come back in the same position

Tags: objective-c, background, youtube-api, video-player

So I managed to play an embeded youtube video in my app. After I press 'done' the app doesn't come back in the same position where it was before playing the video. Please help me with this. This is the way I do it.

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
                    <html><head>\
                    style type=\"text/css\">\
                    body {\
                    background-color: transparent;\
                    color: white;\
                    }\
                    </style>\
                    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
                    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
                    </body></html>";

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    videoView.center=CGPointMake(160, 240);
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
    [videoView release];
}
```

Comment: What embedding are you using?  What exactly does "done" do?  Code or an example link would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had a view which I presented modally. In this case, when youtube goes away and your app comes back to foreground it won't come back in the same position, but in the position before presenting the modal. So I solved my problem by adding that view as a subview rather than presenting it modally.